# Regex capture group that excludes optional substring?

Tags: regex, data-extraction

I'm trying to construct a regex to extract Swedish organization numbers from data. These numbers can be of the following formats:

```
999999999999  // 12 digits, first two should be ignored.
9999999999    // 10 digits, all should be included.
99999999-9999 // 12 digits with a dash, first two digits and the dash should be ignored
999999-9999   // 10 digits with a dash, dash should be ignored.
```

For the 12 digit cases, the first two digits are always 16, 19 or 20. My current attempt is:

```
(?:16|19|20)?(\d{6}\-?\d{4})
```

This will return a ten digit organization number in `$1`, but it will contain the dash if it's present. I want the dash to be stripped (or possibly added if it's missing), so that `$1` has the same format regardless of dash or no dash in the input.

The regex is in a config and will be used in code that simply extracts `$1`, so I can't solve this in code - I need the regex to do it "by itself".

As a last resort, I could modify the code to allow config to specify a "replace string" in addition to the search regex, and have the code use the result of the replace as the end result of the extraction. In that case I could use this:

```
Regex: (?:16|19|20)?(\d{6})\-?(\d{4})
Replace string: $1$2
```

But this causes other problems, because for other config items, the regex will return multiple "data fields", one for each capture group. To get this to work I would need, in that case, to provide a *sequence* of replace strings, e.g. for a tab separated format with organization number in the middle:

```
Regex: ([^\t]*)\t(?:16|19|20)?(\d{6})\-?(\d{4})\t([\d]*)
Replace string 1: $1 (free text field)
Replace string 2: $2-$3 (the organization number with dash "enforced")
Replace string 3: $4 (numeric field)
```

Workable, but rather awkward... So, any way to solve it within the search regex?

Comment: You can't leave out in-between-text inside a single capturing group, that's not how regex works.

Comment: @SebastianProske: I suspected as much.

Comment: @LukStorms: I mentioned that option and why it's workable but awkward in my application.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have now modified the model and code to work with replacement patterns, in addition to the regex, to specify what to extract.